# How to loop through JSON and convert it into Java object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm looking for a good way to loop through JSON object. Looking for example how to do so. Any help is welcome. Need to convert it into Java object. I have read that best way is to use GSON, but could achieve the right result.

```
{  
   "countries":[  
      {  
         "MobileCountry":{  
            "id":2,
            "name":"England",
            "languages":[  
               {  
                  "MobileLanguage":{  
                     "code":"en",
                     "name":"English"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "MobileLanguage":{  
                     "code":"ru",
                     "name":"Russian"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "mobile_code":"+60",
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "regions":[  
               {  
                  "MobileRegion":{  
                     "region_id":2048,
                     "name":"trr"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "MobileRegion":{  
                     "region_id":1024,
                     "name":"Wonderland"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "MobileCountry":{  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Spain",
            "languages":[  
               {  
                  "MobileLanguage":{  
                     "code":"esp",
                     "name":"Spanish"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "MobileLanguage":{  
                     "code":"en",
                     "name":"English"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "mobile_code":"+456",
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "regions":[  
               {  
                  "MobileRegion":{  
                     "region_id":1,
                     "name":"region_1"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "MobileRegion":{  
                     "region_id":8,
                     "name":"region_2"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "MobileRegion":{  
                     "region_id":32,
                     "name":"Region1"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "MobileRegion":{  
                     "region_id":64,
                     "name":"GaBus"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html):

```
String rawJson = "...."; //escape your string if needed!
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do more research and post your code to get more useful feedback.

duplicate:
[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

android has a class for this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Answer (score 0):

This is really a broad question, but I'll try to give an overview of a simple implementation of [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

In short GSON is:

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

Download Gson and add it to your build path. Then, import it to your project:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

Create Gson object to work with:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

Then you can create the JSON by simply passing the object into Gson's [`toJson()` method](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object)):

```
gson.toJson(Object);
```

Or, you could 'consume' a JSON object to create an object back from JSON using the [`fromJson()` method](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)). This works with primitives, or you specify the class the JSON to deserialize into:

```
Person p = gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
```

**Alternatives**

You might want to also check out [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). It looks like it is explicitly referenced in the Android documentation. That library is also pretty popular.